# Efficient upload of large amount of images to Azure Storage in Python

Tags: python, azure, performance, azure-storage

I need to find the optimal way to upload a large number of images (up to a few thousand) of size ~6MB per image on average. Our service is written in Python.

We have the following flow:

1. There is a service that has a single BlobServiceClient created. We are using CertificateCredentials to authenticate
2. Service is running in a container on Linux and written in Python code
3. Service is receiving a message that has 6 to 9 images as Numpy ndarray + JSON metadata object for each
4. every time we get a message we are sending all the files plus JSON files to storage using ThreadPoolExecutor with max_threads = 20
5. We are NOT using the async version of the library

Trimmed out and simplified code will look like this (below will not work, just an illustration, azurestorageclient is out wrapper around Azure Python SDK. It has single BlobServiceClient instance that we are using to create containers and upload blobs):

```
def _upload_file(self,
                 blob_name: str,
                 data: bytes,
                 blob_type: BlobType,
                 length=None):
    blob_client = self._upload_container.get_blob_client(blob_name)
    return blob_client.upload_blob(data, length=len(data), blob_type=BlobType.BlockBlob)

def _upload(self, executor: ThreadPoolExecutor, storage_client: AzureStorageClient,
                  image: ndarray, metadata: str) -> (Future, Future):

    DEFAULT_LOGGER.info(f"Uploading image blob: {img_blob_name} ...")
    img_upload_future = executor.submit(
       self.upload_file,
        blob_name=img_blob_name, byte_array=image.tobytes(),
        content_type="image/jpeg",
        overwrite=True,
    )

    DEFAULT_LOGGER.info(f"Uploading JSON blob: {metadata_blob_name} ...")
    metadata_upload_future = executor.submit(
        self.upload_file,
        blob_name=metadata_blob_name, byte_array=metadata_json_bytes,
        content_type="application/json",
        overwrite=True,
    )

    return img_upload_future, metadata_upload_future

def send(storage_client: AzureStorageClient, 
                image_data: Dict[metadata, ndarray]):

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=_THREAD_SEND_MAX_WORKERS) as executor:
        upload_futures = {
            image_metadata: _upload(
                executor=executor,
                storage_client=storage_client,
                image=image,
                metadata=metadata
            )
            for metadata, image in image_data.items()
        }
```

We observe a very bad performance of such a service when uploading files in a slow network with big signal strength fluctuations.

We are now trying to find and measure different options how to improve performance:

1. We will store files to HDD first and then upload them in bigger chunks from time to time
2. We think that uploading a single big file should perform better (e.g. 100files into zip/tar file)
3. We think that reducing the number of parallel jobs when the connection is bad should be also better
4. We consider using AzCopy instead of Python

Has anyone other suggestions or nice code samples in Python on how to work in such scenarios? Or maybe we should change a service that is used to upload data? For example use ssh to connect to VM and upload files that way (I doubt it will be faster, but got such suggestions).

Mike

Answer (score 2):

According to your situation, I suggest you zip some files as a big file and upload the bigfile in chunks. Regarding how to upload the file in chunks, you can use the method `BlobClient.stage_block` and `BlobClient.commit_block_list` to implement it.

For example

```
block_list=[]
chunk_size=1024
with open('csvfile.csv','rb') as f:
   
   while True:
        read_data = f.read(chunk_size)
        if not read_data:
            break # done
        blk_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        blob_client.stage_block(block_id=blk_id,data=read_data) 
        block_list.append(BlobBlock(block_id=blk_id))
        

blob_client.commit_block_list(block_list)
```

Comment: This is one of the options we consider, however, we need individual files on the storage so we will need to trigger a background process that will unzip and do other work there. We did not calculate the cost of that yet...

Comment: @Kokos If so, I think you can upload every file in small chunks and do not directly upload one whole file content to azure blob. Besides, azcopy is a good choice.

Comment: Hmm interesting. I was thinking the opposite (to increase chunk size so that each file will be sent all at once). Also, I am thinking that we should decrease parallelism when in bad network conditions - too many simultaneous connections. What do you think?

Comment: @Kokos It may be useful. According to the situation, azcopy is a better choice.